# Python program not taking my directory input "Regex File Search"

Tags: python, directory, zip, python-import

I've been working on this for the past week and suddenly it doesn't want to take my input for my directory. Here's my code with comments explaining everything...

```
# Allows us to manipulate directorys
import os
# Allows us to utilize regular expression
import re
# Allows us to open and manipulate zipfiles
import zipfile

# The directory we/re searching in, file search with regex, and line within file with regex
directory = input("Enter directory to search: ")
fileregex = input("Enter filename regex: ")
lineregex = input("Enter line regex: ")

# Walk through the directory and all subdirectories
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    # Loop through all the files in the current directory
    for file in files:
        # Check if the file name matches the regular expression
        if re.match(fileregex, os.path.join(root, file)):
            # If the file is a zip file, use ZipFile to read its contents
            if file.endswith('.zip'):
                with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as zip_file:
                    for member in zip_file.namelist():
                        # Check if the member name (full path) matches the regular expression
                        if re.match(fileregex, os.path.join(root, file, member)):
                            with zip_file.open(member) as f:
                                # Loop through all the lines in the member and check if they match the line regex
                                for line in f:
                                    if re.search(lineregex, line.decode()):
                                        # If there is a match, print the full path to the file and the matching line
                                        print(os.path.join(root, file, member) + ": " + line.decode().strip())
            # If the file is not a zip file, use a regular file read to process its contents
            else:
                with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as f:
                    # Loop through all the lines in the file and check if they match the line regex
                    for line in f:
                        if re.search(lineregex, line):
                            # If there is a match, print the full path to the file and the matching line
                            print(os.path.join(root, file) + ": " + line.strip())
```

The full directory I paste is "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Class\proj-2-files.zip\proj-2-files"... Maybe its an issue on my end so feel free to make a .txt doc and try it out.

After my program started printing out nothing I found that sometimes I would get an error (can't remember it on the top of my head) but essentially the directory didn't exist. So I thought I was typing it wrong. I turned the string into a raw string at one point and tried different ways of typing out the directory and still achieved 0 results.

![Directory]([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxgpu.png))

Comment: _The full directory I paste is "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Class\proj-2-files.zip\proj-2-files"_ Are you sure?  You actually have a **directory** named `proj-2-files.zip`?

Comment: "C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Class\proj-2-files.zip\proj-2-files" is the exact copy and paste of the path. This may be the cause of my confusion? @JohnGordon

Comment: Add this line of code before the loop `print(os.listdir(directory))` and show the output.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: Okay, then that's the problem.  That directory does not exist, as I suspected.  You said it was an "exact copy and paste of the path" -- what path?  Where did you copy and paste **from**?

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely not grasping what a directory is. I got it from file explorer assuming that path leading to proj-2-files was the directory.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the file explorer screen that has the path?

Comment: I can't without 10 reputation sadly